# Dashboard Widget for persistently editing a file

Tags: text-editor, dashboard-widget

Is there a dashboard widget that one can use to persistently edit a text file?

For example, suppose I want to have my `changelog` open all the time in a Git repository.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Dashboard widgets are simple HTML applets, built using HTML, CSS & Javascript. So if there is a way to create an HTML webpage that does this functionality (namely, auto-loading a text file in an editable field with an option to refresh and save), then this can also be accomplished within a Dashboard widget.

It may be worth asking some of the folks at [StackOverflow](http://www.stackoverflow.com) if you need help learning the code to accomplish this (web coding is better suited to that community), and you can use tools like [Dashcode](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action) or [Hype](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/hype/id436931759) (my recommendation) to actually create your widget.

Answer (score 0):

I looked at Apple's [Dashboard developer documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/Dashboard_ProgTopics/Introduction/Introduction.html) and it seems that widgets run in a sort of sandbox within their 'bundle', almost like iOS apps do. That would make it very difficult to implement a text editing widget.

There have been known vulnerabilities in the past, [such as this one in OS X 10.4](http://www1.cs.columbia.edu/~aaron/files/widgets/), that probably make it even more difficult now to circumvent the Dashboard 'sandbox'.

I browsed the different OS X Dashboard widgets in Apple's widget directory and there doesn't seem to be any widgets that may do what you need. Here is the [developer widgets section](https://www.apple.com/downloads/dashboard/developer/), for instance.

There may not be a widget that does exactly what you're looking for. If there is one, it would be a great thing to know about; as I also think that having a quick notepad of sorts in the Dashboard would be quite useful. Good luck on your search.

Comment: I don't think this is quite correct. The documentation clearly states that Dashboard widgets can request permission to read files directly from the filesystem, or to run arbitrary command-line programs.